# Editar PDF con JAVA

Tags: java, pdf

Cordial saludo el motivo de este mensaje es para saber si alguien me puede indicar como editar o insertar un imagen a un archivo PDF mediante JAVA gracias por su atención, quedo atento

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nativamente creo que Java no ofrece nada para la generación y edicion de archivos pdf y de hacerlo desconozco completamente. En estos casos se suele utilizar librerías externas para realizar esta tarea. Tan solo conozco 4, pero estoy seguro que hay muchas más por ahí dando vueltas:

1. [Apache PDF Box](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)
2. [iText PDF](https://itextpdf.com/en)
3. [DynamicReports](https://github.com/dynamicreports/dynamicreports)
4. [PDF Clown](https://pdfclown.org/)

En mi experiencia me gusto mucho **DynamicReports** pero en fin todas hacen lo mismo, es cuestión de gustos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, me sirvió de mucho